# Filebeat kafka input with SASL?

Tags: kafka, filebeat

I'm trying to get filebeat to consume messages from kafka using the kafka input. I'm unable to authenticate with SASL for some reason and I'm not sure why that is. The documentation for both Kafka and Filebeat is a little lacking when trying to use it with SASL.

My filebeat configuration is as follows:

```
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false

filebeat.inputs:
- type: kafka
  hosts: 'the.kafka.server.com:9092'
  topics: 'my_topic'
  group_id: 'my_group'
  ssl.enabled: yes
  username: "$ConnectionString"
  password: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='my_username' password='my_password';"

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~
- add_docker_metadata: ~

output.console:
  pretty: true
```

The output shows

```
INFO    input/input.go:114      Starting input of type: kafka; ID: 14409252276502564738
INFO    kafka/log.go:53 kafka message: Initializing new client
INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker the.kafka.server.com:9092

INFO    crawler/crawler.go:106  Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:171   Config reloader started
INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:226   Loading of config files completed.
INFO    kafka/log.go:53 kafka message: Successful SASL handshake. Available mechanisms: %!(EXTRA []string=[PLAIN OAUTHBEARER])
INFO    kafka/log.go:53 Failed to read response while authenticating with SASL to broker the.kafka.server.com:9092: EOF

INFO    kafka/log.go:53 Closed connection to broker the.kafka.server.com:9092

INFO    kafka/log.go:53 client/metadata got error from broker -1 while fetching metadata: EOF
```

I'm not sure what's happening here. I've also tried adding `compression: none` which didn't help and verified with openssl that the server certificate is able to be verified. What am I doing wrong here? The kafka server in question is a cloud hosted kafka server and I can't see the server configuration, I was given the "connection string" from kafka's cloud UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the `$ConnectionString` syntax doesn't work with confluent cloud kafka clusters. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: kafka
  hosts: 'the.kafka.server.com:9092'
  topics: 'my_topic'
  group_id: 'my_group'
  ssl.enabled: yes
  username: <API KEY>
  password: <API SECRET>
```

That's enough to get it connecting and consuming